# duplicate java actions executed by oozie launcher

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am facing below issue with oozie-5.0.0.

My oozie workflow has a java action which is getting executed twice by the same oozie launcher.

I found that this is happening as oozie launcher is allocated 2 yarn containers and each container invokes the java action thereby executing duplicate actions.

Would just like to know how to avoid duplicate actions from getting executed.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are there any error messages you're seeing in any of the logs? (On the oozie server or in the application logs)

Comment: I am calling a MapReduce job through a java action. MapReduce job executed through both containers allocated to oozie launcher are completing successfully and creating duplicate output in the S3 bucket which is the output location for my MapReduce job. This output is being exported to RDBMS which gives unique key constraint failure due to duplicate records.

Comment: Do both containers have their own application ID or they are multiple attempts for the same application?

Comment: when i listed the containers allocated to oozie launcher it showed me 2 containers as below :
`
$ aws s3 ls s3://path-to-s3-bucket/logs/j-3SHCN0DPKALI/containers/application_1543357164726_0048/
                           PRE container_1543357164726_0048_01_000001/
                           PRE container_1543357164726_0048_02_000001/`